# Can temp tables created in WITH statement reference other tables in the same WITH statement?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, common-table-expression

Can I reference one WITH table from another WITH table?

For example

```
WITH temp1 AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM a
        ),
     temp2 AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT ID
        FROM temp1
        )
SELECT *
FROM temp1, temp2
```

Notice how temp2 references temp1.

My goal is to have several functions in temp1 and then perform aggregations from the temp1 results.

Comment: @sstan thanks and fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct terminology for what you are using is *common table expression*, often abbreviated to CTE. These are not temporary tables.  Even if they are materialized (that is, the results from the execution are saved), the results are only available in a single query.

The answer to your question is that a previous CTE can be used later in the chain of CTEs. It can be used as many times as you need.

Comment: Thank you. This is incredibly powerful functionality. Not directly related to my question, but is there a time where this would be poor practice?

Comment: @AndyLevesque . . . Any code can be sloppy.  I can't think of a situation where CTEs *per se* are a bad choice.

Comment: @AndyLevesque - The only caveat that I'd throw out is that depending on how you are structuring the code, you can make it very difficult for the optimizer to produce optimal plans.  If you have, say, 6 or 7 levels of CTE's and an outer predicate that you really want to be pushed into the lowest level CTE, it may be much more difficult for the optimizer to figure that out than if you had, say, 6 or 7 joins in a somewhat more "hairy" SQL statement.